C# ASP.NET Core Web API : returning list of responses with some error responses
I want to return IEnumerable<MyClass> from my API. My API is taking list of requests and doing parallel tasking for each request so I want to return a proper response for successful request and failure information for failed requests.
In below code I am using Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ActionResult<MyClass>>>>. Populating list with the proper result(MyClass) in case of success and failure result in case of exception. But this looks like not a proper return type to use because we are using Action result in Action result so we are not seeing proper results.
What would the best practice for returning type in these kind of scenarios be?
Please check my code below:
public async <<INeedToDecideonReturnType>> MyOperation1(IEnumerable<Request1> requests)
{

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var results = new ConcurrentBag<ActionResult<MyClass>>();

    foreach (var request in requests)
    {
        tasks.Add(MyOperation(request, results));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return new OkObjectResult(results);
}

public async Task MyOperation(Request1 request, ConcurrentBag<ActionResult<MyClass>> results)
{
    try
    {
        var res = await SomeOperation(request);
        results.Add(res);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        results.Add(new CustomError(ex));
    }
}


Return type from method which handles HTTP requests should be of type IActionResult, ActionResult.
So, I would change return type of SomeOperation to return plain MyClass object, then you can define you return type as IActionResult and return there collection of items of type MyClass.
CustomError also should have nothing to do with returning HTTP response (it seems like it implementes IActionResult).
In my opinion you should not do anything related to HTTP until moment when returning IActionResult from method handling HTTP request. Not deep down in business code.
